# NFS mount: can't find file in /etc/fstab

Tags: linux, mount, nfs, embedded

I have an Arduino Yun with a Linux Arduino 3.3.8 OS on it. The host machine is Ubuntu 14.04. I'm trying to mount a file in my host machine to the board.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NFS-HOWTO/client.html)

The server side is configured: I added a file `example` to `/home/user/Bureau/` and edit the file `/etc/exports`.

Now my problem seems to be on the client side:
I created the directory `/home`.

When I use this command `mount -t 10.160.200.205:/home/user/Bureau/example /home` I got `mount: can't find /home in /etc/fstab`

10.160.200.205 is the IP address of the host machine.

Could anyone help me understand why `mount` is complaining?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

After correcting the command I got

```
mount: mounting 10.160.200.205:/home/user/Bureau/example on /home failed: No such device.
```

It seems that the kernel version flashed in the Arduino does not support NFS because this is the content of the /proc/filesystems, there is no nfs.
In the beginning, I thought that nfs or ntfs is the same thing but it seems it's not the case.

```
nodev   sysfs
nodev   rootfs
nodev   bdev 
nodev   proc
nodev   tmpfs
nodev   debugfs
nodev   sockfs
nodev   usbfs
nodev   pipefs 
nodev   anon_inodefs
nodev   configfs
nodev   devpts
        ext2
        squashfs
nodev   ramfs
        vfat
nodev   jffs2
nodev   overlayfs
nodev   mtd_inodefs
        ext3
        ext4
        reiserfs
        hfs
        hfsplus
        ntfs
        fuseblk
nodev   fuse
nodev   fusectl
```

Comment: I don't think the syntax of your `mount` call is correct. Those parameters seem wrong.

Comment: Thank u for the feedback but could u please explain more what goes wrong, and what is the story behind /etc/fstab, should i update it or ?

Comment: If no entry is in /etc/fstab only root can mount a device. Or with sudo. As User mount complains in this way.

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned by phk, your `mount` syntax is wrong. It should be as follows.

```
mount -t nfs 10.160.200.205:/home/user/Bureau/example /home
```

Or if you want to put that as a permanent mount into `/etc/fstab`

```
10.160.200.205:/home/user/Bureau/example /home    nfs    defaults 0 0
```

Comment: It seems that the kernel version flashed in the Arduino does not support NFS  i thought that nfs or ntfs is the same thing but it seems it's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

nfs layer seems missing, I do interactively mount this way :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rpcbind start
sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-common start
sudo mount 192.168.1.23:/nfs /W2
```

Comment: thank you for the feedback, i'am getting /bin/ash: /etc/init.d/rpcbind: not found the same thing for nfs-common, are you sure that rpcbind and nfs-common are mandatory on the client side, in the tuto am using there is no mention of these services on the client side